# How to get all signature weapon in Far Cry 3

Tags: far-cry-3

I just starting to play the game (Far Cry 3), and somehow, i got the Bull weapon, a signature shotgun without me knowing when I get it, now the question is, how to get other signature weapon, as in what do I have to do to get them all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each signature weapon you need to do tasks like activate a certain amount of radio towers, liberate outposts or find relics.

You can find a complete list of signature weapons and how to get them here:

http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Signature_Weapons

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is there a list of reference like if you activate 2 radio towers you get this, activate 4 towers you get that, things like that?

Comment: Sure, look at the entries for every weapon on that page.